# Opening a file in C through a proccess

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to create a a program that does the following actions:

1. Open a file and read one line.
2. Open another file and read another line.
3. Compare the two lines and print a message.

**This is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int findWord(char sizeLineInput2[512]);

int main()
{
    FILE*cfPtr2,*cfPtr1;
int i;
    char sizeLineInput1[512],sizeLineInput2[512];
    cfPtr2=fopen("mike2.txt","r");
    // I open the first file
while (fgets(sizeLineInput2, 512, cfPtr2)!=NULL)
   // I read from the first 1 file one line 
{
 if (sizeLineInput2[strlen(sizeLineInput2)-1]=='\n')
            sizeLineInput2[strlen(sizeLineInput2)-1]='\0';
             printf("%s \n",sizeLineInput2);
             i=findWord(sizeLineInput2);

   //I call the procedure that compares the two lines

}
getchar();
    return 0;
}
int  findWord(char sizeLineInput2[512])
{
int x;
char sizeLineInput1[512];
File *cfPtr1;
cfPtr1=fopen("mike1.txt","r");

// here I open the second file

     while (fgets(sizeLineInput1, 512,cfPtr1)!=NULL)
     {
        if (sizeLineInput1[strlen(sizeLineInput1)-1]=='\n')
            sizeLineInput1[strlen(sizeLineInput1)-1]='\0';
        if (strcmp(sizeLineInput1,sizeLineInput2)==0)

//Here, I compare the two lines

        printf("the words %s and %s are equal!\n",sizeLineInput1,sizeLineInput2);
        else
        printf("the words %s and %s are not equal!\n",sizeLineInput1,sizeLineInput2);
        }
    fclose(cfPtr1);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to have some problem with file pointers handling. Could someone check it and tell me what corrections I have to do?

Comment: Firstly, you should make some effort to indent your code properly. This would make it much easier to read. Also, a general cleanup will help not only people on SO, but yourself, to diagnose problems. For instance, you declare but never use `cfPtr1` and `sizeLineInput1` in `main()`.

Comment: Also, you never really asked a question. You need to tell us what the problem is first.

Answer (score 2):

#### Deconstruction and Reconstruction

The current code structure is, to be polite about it, cock-eyed.

You should open the files in the same function - probably `main()`.  There should be two parallel blocks of code.  In fact, ideally, you'd do your opening and error handling in a function so that `main()` simply contains:

```
FILE *cfPtr1 = file_open("mike1.txt");
FILE *cfPtr2 = file_open("mike2.txt");
```

If control returns to `main()`, the files are open, ready for use.

You then need to read a line from each file - in `main()` again.  If either file does not contain a line, then you can bail out with an appropriate error:

```
if (fgets(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), cfPtr1) == 0)
    ...error: failed to read file1...
if (fgets(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), cfPtr2) == 0)
    ...error: failed to read file2...
```

Then you call you comparison code with the two lines:

```
findWord(buffer1, buffer2);
```

You need to carefully segregate the I/O operations from the actual processing of data; if you interleave them as in your first attempt, it makes everything very messy.  I/O tends to be messy, simply because you have error conditions to deal with - that's why I shunted the open operation into a separate function (doubly so since you need to do it twice).

You could decide to wrap the `fgets()` call and error handling up in a function, too:

```
const char *file1 = "mike1.txt";
const char *file2 = "mike2.txt";

read_line(cfPtr1, file1, buffer1, sizeof(buffer1));
read_line(cfPtr2, file2, buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));
```

That function can trim the newline off the end of the string and deal with anything else that you want it to do - and report an accurate error, including the file name, if anything goes wrong.  Clearly, with the variables 'file1' and 'file2' on hand, you'd use those instead of literal strings in the `file_open()` calls.  Note, too, that making them into variables means it is trivial to take the file names from the command line; you simply set  'file1' and 'file2' to point to the argument list instead of the hard-wired defaults.  (I actually wrote: `const char file1[] = "mike1.txt";` briefly - but then realized that if you handle the file names via the command line, then you need pointers, not arrays.)

Also, if you open a file, you should close the file too.  Granted, if your program exits, the o/s cleans up behind you, but it is a good discipline to get into.  One reason is that not every program exits (think of the daemons running services on your computer).  Another is that you quite often use a resource (file, in the current discussion) briefly and do not need it again.  You should not hold resources in your program for longer than you need them.

#### Philosophy

Polya, in his 1957 book "How To Solve It", has a dictum:

- Try to treat symmetrically what is symmetrical, and do not destroy wantonly any natural symmetry.

That is as valid advice in programming as it is in mathematics.  And in their classic 1978 book 'The Elements of Programming Style', Kernighan and Plauger make the telling statements:

- [The] subroutine call permits us to summarize the *irregularities* in the argument list [...]
- The subroutine itself summarizes the *regularities* of the code.

In more modern books such as '[The Pragmatic Programmer](http://www.pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer)' by Hunt & Thomas (1999), the dictum is translated into a snappy TLA:

- DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself.

If you find your code doing the 'same' lines of code repeated several times, write a subroutine to do it once and call the subroutine several times.

That is what my suggested rewrite is aiming at.

Comment: I would add: do not emulate standard features. There are no reason to make array of variables: `FILE *file1, *file2`, while can use array variable `FILE *(file[2])`. And then you can simply utilise this symmetry by running counting loop rather that write any code twice. :-)

Comment: @vovanium: yes, you could go to that extreme - and it would be OK.  It might be a bit too dramatically different for the OP, though.  You could simply have: `void get_first_line_from_file(const char *filename, char *buffer, size_t buflen);` and use that to collect one line from each file - hiding the open, read and close in the function.  Depending on the return type, you might even be able to simply pass the result direct to the comparator: `findWord(get_line_from_file("mike1.txt", buffer1, sizeof(buffer1)), get_line_from_file("mike2.txt", buffer2, sizeof(buffer2)));`.  And so on...

Comment: Oh, that's about functional programming paradigm. :) I also would like write this in one expression, but there's not enough FP syntax in C... And i would write this in two: prepare array of strings in first, pass array (as sinle parameter) to `findWord()` in second.

Answer (score -1):

In both `main()` and `findWord()` you should not use `strlen(sizeLineInputX)` right after reading the file with `fgets()` - there may be no `'\0'` in `sizeLineInput2` and you will have `strlen()` read beyond the 512 bytes you have.

Instead of using `fgets` use `fgetc` to read char by char and check for a newline character (and for `EOF` too).

UPD to your UPD: you compare each line of mike2.txt with each line of mike1.txt - i guess that's not what you want. Open both files one outside `while` loop in `main()`, use one loop for both files and check for newline and `EOF` on both of them in that loop.

Comment: fgets() will always append a `'\0'`

Comment: `fgets()` always null terminates its output unless the buffer size is zero.  Clearly, a buffer size of one does not get any useful data in it.

Comment: Ah, yes, i'm wrong about it. The only upd part should be considered.